# Benchmarking performance in CFD: how to compare machines and codes?

Tags: performance, fluid-dynamics, hpc, benchmarking

Informally in our lab, we have developed 2 metrics to compare CFD solvers over
the range of machines we have access to.  One is called **COMP**, which stands
for COde Machine Performance. This single number is supposed to represent the
absolute performance of a given code on a given machine. It is computed, for a
given run, by multiplying the number of cells per computing/processing core by
the number of iterations performed and then dividing by the runtime. In an
ideal situation, this number should be constant no matter the number of cores
being used, the size of the grid or the duration of the run. It directly
indicates on how many cells one iteration can be performed by one core in one
second. By extension, the acronym COMP will be used as unit for measuring the
performance of the codes. For examples, if a given run yields "3.2 k COMPs", it
means the code is able to process one iteration on 3200 cells per core per
second, or 3200 iterations on one cell per core per second, or any similar
combination.  Derived from COMP, we have obvious metrics like speed, speed-up
and efficiency, which are just expressing in different ways raw performance and
scaling.

The other metric, which is designed to compare the efficiency of different
schemes/codes on the same machines, simply looks at the amount of CPU time
required per unit of physical time simulated. Of course, this leaves many parameters out
of the analysis, like the grid or the accuracy of the obtained solution. But we
strive to compare runs on equivalent grid/accuracy (for example, if you compare a 4th order
scheme with a 2nd order scheme, you should probably use half as many points for
a similar accuracy).

What do you think of these metrics? Do they appear valid to you? Do you know or
use other similar metrics to benchmark your CFD solver?

I should also add that we usually deal with explicit schemes on structured 
grids, although we are now starting to do some comparisons with a DG code. The
reasoning might be different for unstructured grids and/or implicit schemes.

Comment: My single measure is wall-time required to achieve a desired solution error. If you are comparing different methods, try to choose the coarsest grid and largest time step that satisfies the desired error. Then you can compare different methods (or different "tweaked" versions of the same method)  against something you should care about: How much is it going to cost me (time/money...) to achieve a desired solution error? Note that this works for time-dependent as well as for steady state problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the day, the only things that matter are **wall-clock time to a chosen accuracy** and **Watts (or dollars) to a chosen accuracy**.

For implementation and hardware performance, I like to measure in terms of memory bandwidth and flop/s per Watt or per dollar. If the performance of the code is very far below the hardware peak according to these metrics, then there is likely some implementation inefficiency. Alternatively, if even very simple benchmarks like [STREAM](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/) perform well below machine peak, then the machine may have bottlenecks that reduce its realizable performance.

The efficiency of an algorithm really can't be measured by "cells per second" except within a restricted class. If you measure by that metric, I argue that you have missed the point.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough in that the COMP metric can indeed only be used to compare machines with the same code or the evolution of a given code.